# how do I retain a leading zero when concatinating values in MS Access?

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am running a concatenation of 2 fields which are number fields formatted to `00`. This was intended to add a leading zero for numbers 1-9. In a form I have begun to concatenate these two together however I am losing the leading 0.

```
Private Sub PartCodeBtn_Click()
Dim GroupVal As String
Dim CatVal As string

GroupVal = Me!Prt_GroupDS.Form![Group_Number]
CatVal = Me!Part_Cat_DS.Form![PartCat_Number]

part_type_code = GroupVal & " " & CatVal
```

I am getting a part type code result of `32 1` instead of `32 01`. 
does anyone know how to keep the leading zero, or why I have lost it?

Comment: You are losing it because the formatting information specified in the numeric field is used for display purposes only in Access.  It is not actually part of the data returned from the field, and numbers will always be returned without leading zeros.

Comment: Ah right! that does make sense actually. I guess the easiest way is to use a text field then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take it that part_type_code is a string, so try:

```
part_type_code = Format$(GroupVal, "00") & " " & Format$(CatVal, "00")
```